# Windows 10 booting from unalloted space

Tags: windows-10, boot

[image]

I installed windows 10 on my computer. Then installed it on a different partition on the same computer keeping the other install. But I deleted the secondary windows so it is unallocated space. It is trying to go to the unallocated space, how do I get it to go to the older install?

Comment: What do you mean "It is trying to go to the unallocated space" ? If you can post screen shot and give more clarity.

Comment: Note I am using ubuntu.

Comment: What exactly is "it", when you say, "It is trying to go to the unallocated space"

Comment: The boot, it will boot into the empty space.

Comment: Are you saying that your bootloader is trying to run the Windows 10 installation that you deleted?

Comment: Yes. I'm using ubuntu right now, so if you need a backup OS, I can use that.